# Module import undefined in jest test file

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to unit test a utility file (util.js) with jest and the file looks like,

// utils.js

```
import { something } from '@whatever/nothing';

export const myMethod = (parameter) => {

    if (!something ) return 0;
    return something.length + parameter.length;
};
```

// utils.test.js

```
import { myMethod } from '../utils';

    test('myMethod', () => {
        expect(myMethod('whatever').toEqual(12);
    });
```

> **something is module which is exported with a value of 'temp'.**

When I run the test file, ***something*** is always ***undefined*** and ends up returning `0`. What is the right way to mock the module '`something`' inside the test file and make it available in the test run?

Answer (score -3):

The way to mock `something` is this:

```js
import { something } from '@whatever/nothing';
import { myMethod } from '../utils';

jest.mock('@whatever/nothing');
something.mockReturnValue('temp');

test('myMethod', () => {
  expect(myMethod('whatever').toEqual(12);
});
```

`jest.mock('@whatever/nothing');` Creates the mock of your module.

`something.mockReturnValue('temp');` Creates the return value that is going to be in something.

Comment: something is not a function, it needs to be mocked and tested in another way.

Comment: I just modified my example using `mockReturnValue `. With this, `something` is going to be a string.

Comment: No, it won't because Jest mocking doesn't work as you expect, JS doesn't work like that too. There's no way how you could make a variable like `something` have `mockReturnValue` method that makes it equal to different values like `something.mockReturnValue(12); expect(something).toBe(12)`. Jest spies are applicable only to functions (and also descriptor accessors). `something` is not a function. It's an object and used as `something.length`, not `something()`. Try to test the solution you're suggesting and you'll see.

Comment: Say I have export function foo(){//something}; and that is import using es6 module syntax. I found that it is also undefined in a jest file. Should this function also be mocked? jest.mock("pathtofunction", () => { foo: jest.fn()}); I feel we should be able to call into foo() without having to mock it to assert on the output. If we are mocking the output then assertion on the mock output seems pointless?